# std::make_pair, std::unordered_map and usage of move constructor from key type

Tags: c++, move

Given following struct:

```
struct FieldNo
{
    FieldNo() : a('0'), b('0') {}
    FieldNo(char a_, char b_) : a(a_), b(_b) {}
    // copy construction and assigment not allowed
    FieldNo(const FieldNo& other) = delete;
    FieldNo& operator=(const FieldNo& other) = delete;
    // move construction and assignment ok
    FieldNo(FieldNo&& other) = default;
    FieldNo& operator=(FieldNo&& other) = default; 

    char a;
    char b;
};

enum class Members : int8_t
{
    FOO,
    BAR
};
```

I am using `FieldNo` as key and `Member` as value for an std::unordered_map. Ommitting the code for the hash creation function, my map is defined as following:

```
typedef std::unordered_map<FieldNo, Members, FieldNoHasher> MyMapT;
```

Later I use following method to initialize and return to the caller

```
const MyMapT& map()
{
   static const MyMapT fields = 
   {
       std::make_pair(FieldNo('0', '5'), Members::FOO),
       std::make_pair(FieldNo('1', 'X'), Members::BAR)
   }
   return fields;
}
```

At first the copy constructor was not deleted and everything worked fine.

As I deleted to copy constructor I am getting loads of errors in insertion and put here the most relevant one:

```
[build] 
[build] /usr/include/c++/8/ext/new_allocator.h:136:4: error: use of deleted function ‘constexpr std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&) [with _T1 = const FieldNo; _T2 = Members]’
[build]   { ::new((void *)__p) _Up(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
[build]     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[build] In file included from /usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_algobase.h:64,
[build]                  from /usr/include/c++/8/bits/char_traits.h:39,
[build]                  from /usr/include/c++/8/ios:40,
[build]                  from /usr/include/c++/8/istream:38,
[build]                  from /usr/include/c++/8/fstream:38,
[build]                  from 
[build] /usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_pair.h:303:17: note: ‘constexpr std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&) [with _T1 = const FieldNo; _T2 = Members]’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
[build]        constexpr pair(const pair&) = default;
[build]                  ^~~~
[build] /usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_pair.h:303:17: error: use of deleted function ‘FieldNo::FieldNo(const libtraco::FieldNo&)’
```

I know the errors are related due to the missing copy constructor. But why does it even try to copy things? `FieldNo('0', '5')` in `std::make_pair` is clearly a `rvalue`.
Am I missing something?

Thanks!

EDIT: Minimal reproducible example added

```
#include <unordered_map>

struct FieldNo
{
    FieldNo() : a('0'), b('0') {}
    FieldNo(char a_, char b_) : a(a_), b(b_) {}
    // copy construction and assigment not allowed
    FieldNo(const FieldNo& other) = delete;
    FieldNo& operator=(const FieldNo& other) = delete;
    // move construction and assignment ok
    FieldNo(FieldNo&& other) = default;
    FieldNo& operator=(FieldNo&& other) = default;

    bool operator==(const FieldNo& lhs) const
    {
        return a == lhs.a && b == lhs.b;
    }

    char a;
    char b;
};

template <class T>
inline void hash_combine(std::size_t& seed, const T& v)
{
    std::hash<T> hasher;
    seed ^= hasher(v) + 0x9e3779b9 + (seed<<6) + (seed>>2);
}

struct FieldNoHasher 
{
    std::size_t operator()(const FieldNo& input) const
    {
        std::size_t seed = 0;
        hash_combine(seed, input.a);
        hash_combine(seed, input.b);
        return seed;
    }
};

enum class Members : int8_t
{
    FOO,
    BAR
};

typedef std::unordered_map<FieldNo, Members, FieldNoHasher> MyMapT;

const MyMapT& map()
{
   static const MyMapT fields = 
   {
       std::make_pair(FieldNo('0', '5'), Members::FOO),
       std::make_pair(FieldNo('1', 'X'), Members::BAR)
   };

   return fields;
}

int main()
{
    map();
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre].  Use the simplest configuration that can still reproduce the problem (e.g., use `int` instead of an enum).

Comment: The error is not that it is trying to copy the `FieldNo('0', '5')` rvalue inside `std::make_pair` but that somewhere in the internals of the map a pair is copied.

Comment: @L. F. This is already simplified. I can provide the full code including FieldNoHasher but you need boost to compile as it uses boost::hash_combine. I am open to any input but it is hardly unlikely that the enum causes the issue as the error complains about the key_type that is FieldNo.

Comment: @MaxLanghof You are absolutely right, but I assumed that this takes place during insertion and would not happen in case the map uses move construction in first place.

Comment: @Paxi1337 Here's what a minimal reproducible example is supposed to look like: https://wandbox.org/permlink/Opd5HkVIvE5F1mED

Comment: I added it. Boost is also not necessary anymore. As you remove deleted from the copy ctor it will compile

Comment: You didn't. It's still not minimal, as LF has shown.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a minimal reproducible example:

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <utility>

class C {
public:
    C() = default;
    C(const C&) = delete;
    C& operator=(const C&) = delete;
    C(C&&) = default;
    C& operator=(C&&) = default;
};

bool operator==(const C&, const C&)
{
    return true;
}

struct Hash {
    constexpr std::size_t operator()(const C&) const
    {
        return 42;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::unordered_map<C, int, Hash> map {
        std::make_pair(C{}, 0)
    };
}
```

([live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Opd5HkVIvE5F1mED))

The problem is that you are calling the `initializer_list` constructor.  Because of the way `initializer_list` works, the underlying elements of an `initializer_list` are `const`, meaning the elements can only be copied, not moved.  You cannot use the `initializer_list` constructor if your type is move only.  You have to use the other facilities:

```
std::unordered_map<C, int, Hash> map;
map.emplace(C{}, 0);
```

or you can replace `initializer_list` with another container that supports moving (a vector, for example):

```
std::vector<std::pair<const C, int>> values {
    std::make_pair(C{}, 0)
};
std::unordered_map<C, int, Hash> map(values.cbegin(), values.cend());
```

([live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/hGYayIvOlqlNLXuZ))

Comment: An `initializer_list` is not inherently `const` but its members are

Comment: Well thanks that covers it. In this case, however, I cannot initialize the static map as I intended to and return it right away. So I guess I will wrap up the emplaces into a second static function and assign the returned map to my map.

Comment: @Paxi1337 do you **really** need to delete those operators?

Comment: Actually not. It was more like an experiment. Just being curious :D

Comment: @Paxi1337 I updated my answer with a way to initialize the static map.